# Grails twitter-bootstrap plugin Resource not found

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I've searched stackoverflow for this and found some similar references but not concrete solutions...

I am using Grails 2.4.2 with the twitter-bootstrap:3.2.1 plugin but get the following errors during run-app:

```
| Error 2014-07-26 11:51:48,592 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /assets/bootstrap-fixtaglib.css
| Error 2014-07-26 11:51:48,668 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /assets/bootstrap.css
| Error 2014-07-26 11:51:48,725 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /assets/bootstrap-theme.css
| Error 2014-07-26 11:51:48,778 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /assets/bootstrap-alert.js
| Error 2014-07-26 11:51:48,807 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /assets/bootstrap-affix.js
| Error 2014-07-26 11:51:48,837 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /assets/bootstrap-dropdown.js
| Error 2014-07-26 11:51:48,860 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /assets/bootstrap-modal.js
| Error 2014-07-26 11:51:48,888 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /assets/bootstrap-popover.js
| Error 2014-07-26 11:51:48,907 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /assets/bootstrap-scrollspy.js
| Error 2014-07-26 11:51:48,921 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /assets/bootstrap-tab.js
| Error 2014-07-26 11:51:48,934 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /assets/bootstrap-tooltip.js
| Error 2014-07-26 11:51:48,947 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /assets/bootstrap-button.js
| Error 2014-07-26 11:51:48,959 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /assets/bootstrap-carousel.js
| Error 2014-07-26 11:51:48,977 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /assets/bootstrap-collapse.js
| Error 2014-07-26 11:51:48,996 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /assets/bootstrap-transition.js
| Error 2014-07-26 11:51:49,012 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /assets/bootstrap.less
```

The whole point of the plugin is to streamline the asset pipeline and have the plugin put everything in proper place.

I have my BuildConfig.groovy setup to pull the plugin in:

```
...
plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.54"

    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
    //compile ':cache:1.1.7'
    compile ":asset-pipeline:1.8.11"
    compile ":twitter-bootstrap:3.2.1"

    // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
    //runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.4" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.16"
    //runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
    runtime ":resources:1.2.8"

    // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
    //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.7.4"
    compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.7.0"
    //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.7.0"
    //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
}
...
```

I have my GSP setup properly as far as I can tell:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Task Master - Tasks</title>
    <r:require module="jquery"/>
    <r:require module="bootstrap-js"/>
    <r:require module="bootstrap"/>
    <r:layoutResources/>
</head>

<body class="container">

    <h1>Task Master - Tasks</h1>
    <r:layoutResources/>
</body>
</html>
```

I checked and they aren't under /assets as the errors state.  I saw where some people hacked a solution by manually copying the assets but then is there a point to the plugin at all?  Either I am missing something simple or there is a bug in the plugin.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

--Ryan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Grails 2.4, asset-pipeline is the default mechanism to get static resources to the client. In your BuildConfig "asset-pipeline" as well as "resources" (the pre 2.4 default mechanism) are used. I'm not sure, if this configuration is really what you want and if it even works at all.

A valid configuration with only asset-pipeline should be:

BuildConfig.groovy:

```
plugins {
    compile ":asset-pipeline:1.8.11"
    compile ":twitter-bootstrap:3.2.1"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
}
```

grails-app/views/layouts/main.gsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Task Master - Tasks</title>
    <asset:stylesheet href="application.css"/>
</head>

<body class="container">
    <h1>Task Master - Tasks</h1>
    <asset:javascript src="application.js"/>
</body>
</html>
```

grals-app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:

```
/*
*= require bootstrap
*= require_tree .
*/
```

grals-app/assets/javascript/application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

For more information see the docs of the [asset-pipeline plugin](http://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/) as well as the docs of the [twitter-bootstrap](https://github.com/groovydev/twitter-bootstrap-grails-plugin#including-the-resources-with-asset-pipeline-plugin) plugin.

> I checked and they aren't under /assets as the errors state

This is true, because nothing will be copied in your application, but instead the resources live in the [assets directory](https://github.com/groovydev/twitter-bootstrap-grails-plugin/tree/master/grails-app/assets) of the bootstrap plugin. The asset-pipeline plugin scans every plugin for a assets folder (or the web-app folder for compatibility purposes) and combines this, so in the generated war, all resources are available.

Comment: Thanks Mario.  I will give this a shot tonight.

Comment: I gave this a try and the errors went away when I removed the ":resources:1.2.8" plugin.  Together they seem to conflict.  I want to figure out a couple of items with Bootstrap to make sure I have everything working.  Thanks.

Comment: I'll second this, I removed the resources plugin in buildConfig.groovy and it solved this same issue

Comment: typo: s/grals-app/grails-app/g